# Why wont passport.authenticate do anything despite it seeming to have no errors

Tags: node.js

I am writing an Express app using Passport and PostgreSQL for account creation and login.

All of the database parts are working fine but when it gets to `passport.authenticate` nothing seems to happen.

I've tried modifying my code to better match examples I found online but haven't been able to get anything back from any of the print statements.

Here's some of the code from my index.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const session = require("express-session");
const { response } = require("express");
const passport = require("passport");
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const db = require("./dbManager.js")

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/Public"));
app.use(session({
  secret: "example",
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//Uses pasport to authenticate user
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email',
  passwordField: 'password'
}, function (email, password, done) {
  console.log("Logging in ", email);
  //This sends the query to the db
  db.findUser(email).then(function (row) {
    if (!row) {
      return done(null, false, "Sorry that user doesn't exist");
    } else {
      //This compairs the passwords
      bcrypt.compare(password, row.password, function (ex, result) {
        //Checks if they match
        if (result == true) {
          //Sets up user
          done(null, row.id);
        } else {
          return done(ex, false, "Incorrect password");
        }
      })
    }
  }).catch(function (ex) {
    console.error(ex);
    return done(ex, false);
  });
}));

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  console.log(user, done);
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
  db.deserializeUser(id).then(function (row) {
    console.log("User found id is:", row.id);
    done(null, row.id)
  }).catch(function (ex) {
    console.error(ex);
  })
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Server running on port 3000');
});

app.get("/createAccount", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/Public/Create Account/createAccount.html");
});

app.post("/createAccount", function (req, res) {
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;

  bcrypt.hash(password, 10, function (ex, hashedPassword) {
    if (ex != null) {
      console.log(ex);
    }

    db.addUser(email, hashedPassword).then(function () {
      console.log("New user added");
      res.status(204).send("user added");
    }).catch(function (ex) {
      console.error(ex);
      res.status(403).send(ex);
    });
  });
});

app.get("/logIn", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/Log In/login.html");
});

app.post("/logIn", function (req, res) {
  console.log("Logging user in");
  passport.authenticate("local", function (ex, user, info) {
    console.log("Authentication");
    if (ex) {
      console.error(ex);
      res.status(403).send(ex);
    } else if (!user) {
      console.log(info);
      res.status(400).send(info);
    } else {
      req.logIn(user, function (ex) {
        if (ex) {
          console.error(ex);
          res.status(400).send(ex);
        } else {
          console.log("User now authenticated");
          res.status(200).send("Success");
        }
      })
    }
  });
});
```

Here is code from my createAccount.js script:

```
//This will run when the form is submitted
$("#submitBtn").click(function() {
    //prepares data to be sent
    body= {
        email:$("#email")[0].value,
        password:$("#password")[0].value
    };
    //This sends the post request to the server
    $.post("/createAccount",body).done(accountCreated(body)).fail(accountNotCreated);
});


function accountCreated(body) {
    console.log("User Added");
    console.log(body.email);
    //Sends post request to log user in
    $.post("/logIn",body).done(function() {
        console.log("You are now logged in");
        window.location.replace("/");
    }).fail(function(ex) {
        console.error(ex);
    });
}

function accountNotCreated(ex) {
    console.error(ex);
}
```

The log output for this is as follows:

```
Logging user in
New user added
```

I'm not sure why this is in the wrong order either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are running the `accountCreated` function **before** you make the post to */createAccount*. This line is the culprit

```js
$.post("/createAccount",body).done(accountCreated(body)).fail(accountNotCreated);
```

This line of code is supposed to be setting up the accountCreated function to run after the call to `$.post` finishes successfully. However, because you're including the brackets after the function it's executing the function immediately and using whatever is returned as the handler for when the post completes.

You can fix this by wrapping the call to accountCreated in an anonymous function.

```js
$.post("/createAccount",body).done(function() { 
accountCreated(body)
}).fail(accountNotCreated);
```

I hope that helps.